# What is the difference between clojure.string/replace vs .replace in ClojureScript?

Tags: replace, clojurescript

I tried the two options:

```
(.replace my-string "string-to-replace" "new-string"))
```

and:

```
(.clojure.string/replace my-string "string-to-replace" "new-string"))
```

I can use the both, but I don't know what is the difference, can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(.replace my-string) - this is JavaScript method String.prototype.replace()

(clojure.string/replace) is [a wrapper](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1.10.439/src/main/cljs/clojure/string.cljs#L44-L74) for the same js method